# Use Facebook status on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is there a way to show facebook status from my visitors to my visitors on my website? 
(googled for hours, could not find anything)

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Thanks, however I was kinda hoping someone already coded something like this..(:

Comment: You mean who is watching your website?